# Google Apps Script suddenly started throwing 'invalid mime type' errors

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have a script which processes a shared mailbox and forwards on different email (based on things like the original 'To:' header to various people. It's been working fine for months as a more flexible (and, up till now, reliable) replacement for gmail filters.

The logic is basically

1. Read each unprocessed message in the inbox
2. Look up who it was sent 'To:' (e.g. support@domain.com) which is an alias for this gmail inbox
3. Get a list of the intended recipients (within our organistion)
4. For each of those, forward the message on
5. Mark that message as processed, so it doesn't get re-forwarded next time

We've recently received an email which seems to trigger a weird error at the point at which the message is forwarded on. The error is:

> Invalid mime type. (line 123, file "Code").

Line 123 of the script reads:

```
// subject: removes the 'Fwd:' prefix which we don't need, and adds the original target email in square brackets, and sets the replyTo for easy processing
really && msg.forward(rcvr, {subject: msg.getSubject() + " [" + thisTo + "]", replyTo: msg.getFrom()});
```

Here's a summary of the interesting bits:

- `really` is just a boolean so we can do 'dry runs' for testing
- `msg` is set to the current message being processed, and is of type `GmailMessage`
- `rcvr` is a string with the recipient's email address
- `thisTo` is a string holding the original 'To:' header

The message in question is a multi-part mime email with plain text and html in it. It displays just fine in gmail, and I can forward it on from there without problems. So, could anyone shed light on what the script engine is complaining about? The raw email looks like this (with some bits taken out for privacy) in case that helps pin it down:

```
Delivered-To: XXXX@YYYY.com
Received: by 10.182.155.73 with SMTP id vj5sqase239pbc;
        Wed, 26 Jun 2013 08:50:48 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.68.166.5 with SMTP id zc5m425et238pbb.16.1372261847795;
        Wed, 26 Jun 2013 08:50:47 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <support@ZZZZ.com>
Received: from mail.ZZZZ.com (mail.ZZZZ.com. [64.78.193.232])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id vj5sqwefwe239pbc.316.2013.06.26.08.50.47
        for <multiple recipients>;
        Wed, 26 Jun 2013 08:50:47 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of support@ZZZZ.com designates aa.bb.cc.dd as permitted sender) client-ip=aa.bb.cc.dd;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of support@ZZZZ.com designates aa.bb.cc.dd as permitted sender) smtp.mail=support@ZZZZ.com
Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 09:50:46 -0600
To: AAAA@YYYY.com, XXXX@YYYY.com
From: ZZZZ <support@ZZZZ.com>
Reply-to: ZZZZ <support@ZZZZ.com>
Subject: ZZZZ (Order #00412744)
Message-ID: <805b426783f23fec38ddafb002ce40b@admin.ZZZZ.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_805b426783ff4601fbe72afb002ce40b"


--b1_805b426783ff4601fbe72afb002ce40b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset = "utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello Andy,

[SNIP]

and destroy all copies of the original message. Thank You


--b1_805b426783ff4601fbe72afb002ce40b
Content-Type: text/html; charset = "utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<head>
</head>

[SNIP]

and destroy all copies of the original message. Thank You</span></font></p></td></tr></tbody></table></body>
</html>



--b1_805b426783ff4601fbe72afb002ce40b--
```

Comment: were you able to fix it ? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: No, but it's very sporadic, and seems to have dropped in frequency recently. I do still get occasional failures, but not of this kind any more - the ones I get now look like temporary 'network unavailable' type messages (e.g. Cannot connect to Google Mail).

Comment: Looks that this problem can't be reproduced and/or solved by developers, instead it could be a performance/reliability issue that should be solved by Google. In case that this issue persist, post an issue to https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Comment: Could you please share your code. If possible

Comment: Sorry, can't share the whole code, and haven't had this issue in a couple of years now.